# Portal lab monitor text

Tags: portal

Where could I find a full text dump of the gibberish text from Portal's lab monitors?

[image: https://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120621181738/half-life/en/images/3/31/Lab_monitor_screen_text.png]

Comment: The ingredients to Vanilla Crazy cake. GlaDoS version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not appear entirely accurate, but it was the best I could find. Hope it helps!
http://pastebin.com/hghRFv7Y

Comment: That's good enough for me :D

Comment: For the record, [I recreated this using Node.JS](https://gist.github.com/Qix-/cc90789f0bd31473cd31). Have fun.